# How do I fill a column of an array with the contents of another array?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Preferably without using loops, is it possible to fill the contents of an empty array, let's call it `C` with the contents of two other arrays, let's call them `A` and `B`?

```
Dim A() As Double
Dim B() As Double
ReDim A(1 To 100,1 To 1)
ReDim B(1 To 100,1 To 1)


' fill A and B with stuff...

Dim C As Double

' I now want "A" to form the first column and "B" to form the second column of array C

C(1 To 100, 1) = A(1 To 100, 1) ' Compile error at '=': Expected end of statement
C(1 To 100, 2) = B(1 To 100, 1) ' Compile error at '=': Expected end of statement
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VBA doesn't have that kind of array assignment.

Comment: Yes it is possible. One moment. Posting a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using a Range like this if I were on your shoes:

```
Sub sample()

Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
Dim i As Long, j As Long

A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
B = Array(5, 6, 7, 8)

Range("A1:A" & UBound(A) + 1) = Application.Transpose(A)
Range("B1:B" & UBound(B) + 1) = Application.Transpose(B)

C = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:B" & UBound(B) + 1))
'~~> Just to test the array elements
For i = 1 To UBound(C, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(C, 2)
        Debug.Print C(i, j)
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Not very neat but it will give you what you want.
Also, Siddhart is correct, declare variables as `Variant` type.

Answer (score 3):

> Preferably without using loops, is it possible to fill the contents of an empty array

Like I mentioned in comments, it **IS POSSIBLE** to combine two arrays into the third array ***without using a loop***.

The key to do this is that you do not use `Double` as the Array Type but use `Variant`. See this example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim A(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim B(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim C As Variant
    Dim Ub_A As Long, Ub_B As Long, i As Long
    Dim sA As String, sB As String, sAB As String

    '~~> Assign sample data to array A and B
    A(1) = 1: A(2) = 2: B(1) = 3: B(2) = 4

    Ub_A = UBound(A): Ub_B = UBound(B)

    sA = "{" & Join(A, ",") & "},"
    sB = "{" & Rept("0,", Ub_A) & Join(B, ",") & "},"

    sAB = "{" & Rept("1,", Ub_A) & Rept("2,", Ub_B)
    sAB = Left(sAB, Len(sAB) - 1) & "},"

    '~~> Construct your C Array
    C = Evaluate("Choose(" & sAB & sA & sB & ")")

    '~~> For testing purpose only to check the elements of C Array
    For i = LBound(C) To UBound(C)
        Debug.Print ">>"; C(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function Rept(s As String, j As Long) As String
    Rept = Replace(Space(j), " ", s)
End Function
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Nice one Siddharth.  But I bet the OP will be ok with loops now. ;-)

Comment: Lol@TimWilliams: I would prefer loops. Gives a better control over the code :)

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, you definitely answered the question! But yeah Tim is right!